# (JAVA) Checking whether input string contains a certain word (definite) and removing it

Tags: java, string, substring

Let's say I have an input string of 6 characters followed by a word "hello"

```
abcdefhello
```

or another set of data

```
quernwegngweghello
```

I mean, the word "hello" will definitely be at the end. How can I remove the word if possible?

The string is dynamic in number, meaning it will change accordingly so I will like to check whether the word contains "hello" in the last 5 characters and remove them if possible.

Comment: Take a substring... or a regex. I think you answered your own question with the tags.

Comment: 1. Why is this tagged `jsp`?

Comment: Did you *bother* to read the javadoc of the [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class? If you had, you might have found such useful methods as `endsWith()` and `substring()`. Down-vote for lack for research!!

Comment: String x="ghhgghello";
  if(x.endsWith("hello"))
  {
   
  }...........Remove the word from where ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static String stripHelloFromEnd(String input) {
  if (input.endsWith("hello")) {
    return input.substring(0, input.length() - "hello".length());
  }
  return input;
}
```